# Import a module named the same as the grandparent package

Tags: python, flask

In Python 2.6.6, I have a module named the same as its grandparent. My project structure (a web app using Flask) looks roughly like this:

```
panel/
  run.py
  panel/
    __init__.py
    database.py
    views/
      __init__.py
      root.py
      dash.py
      panel.py
    users/
      __init__.py
      models.py
```

Note that the package name, next to run.py, is **panel**. I also have a module named **panel.views.panel**. If from within panel/__init__.py I import panel.views.panel, using any of these three styles:

```
from panel.views import panel
from panel.views import panel as panel_view
import panel.views.panel as panel_view
```

After importing **panel.py**, none of my other imports work. For example, panel.users.models attempts to import database.py, and this traceback is thrown:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "run.py", line 5, in <module>
    from panel import app
  File "/opt/www/panel/panel/__init__.py", line 8, in <module>
    from panel.views import root
  File "/opt/www/panel/panel/views/root.py", line 9, in <module>
    from panel import database;
ImportError: cannot import name database
```

I spoke with a few people in the #pocoo IRC channel, and from what they described, the issue is that from within views/root.py, Python thinks `import panel.database` means to import `database` from **panel.py** sitting next to it.

This doesn't make sense to me though because [PEP 328](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0328/) outlines (what reads like) this exact problem, and made absolute imports the default in order to fix this. I'm using Python 2.6.6, so this should be the default. Just to be sure though, I added the line `from __future__ import absolute_import` but this didn't make a difference; the same error importing database.py occurred.

Renaming **panel.py** fixes this issue, however, I'm extremely curious to know why this doesn't work as it is written, and especially if there's anything I can do to make this work.

Comment: dont do that please... bad style...

Comment: There's usually a difference between "bad style" and "is incapable of working that way" and even if it's bad style, I'd like to understand why it doesn't work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You said you added the line `from __future__ import absolute_import`, but you didn't say to which file you added it.  Be sure to add it to root.py.

This section of the python tutorial explains what is happening in your case: http://docs.python.org/tutorial/modules.html#intra-package-references

Comment: Adding that line to root.py seems to have fixed my problem. But I don't understand why, since absolute imports should be the default in my version of Python (2.6.6). From the PEP I linked, importing absolute_import is required for Python 2.5. Also from the PEP, "In Python 2.6, any import statement that results in an intra-package import will raise DeprecationWarning..." Can you comment on this?